# How to make secure when hosting website in EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have followed the below steps to make it https but still i am seeing the site is insecure.. what else i am missing?

1. Uploaded content in S3 Bucket
2. Created EC2 Instance with security group for port 22 and 80 to allow 0.0.0.0/0
3. Installed apache and started the services in the ec2 instance
4. Created ELB and added listeners to route

   http to https

   https to target group
5. Registered Target and when I launch url (DNS name in ELB), I am getting still insecure..

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I launch url (DNS name in ELB)

You can't use the ELB's DNS name if you want to use SSL, because you won't be able to have an SSL certificate that matches that DNS name. You have to point a domain name at the ELB that you own, and use an SSL certificate that matches that domain name.

Comment: Without registered domain, EC2 instances hosted website can't open in HTTPS??

Comment: You can't create a valid SSL certificate that a web browser will accept unless you own (or control) the domain name. This is a universal truth across all web hosting, not just AWS.